# MS Visual Studio not highlighting functions correctly and not displaying documentation nor autofilling

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio-2010

i am using MS Visual Studio 2022 Community Edition to work on a project together with a colleague which I previously cloned. The project folder seems to be correctly cloned and yet the functions are not highlighted in the same way as with my colleague and I don't get documentation displayed by hovering above the function. Furthermore, adding a '.' after a function does not open up a list of functions. Anybody know how to fix this?

I tried the following things:
-Clone another time
-Restart the IDE
-Make sure that under Options\Text-Editor\C# everything is activated

Thanks for the help

Comment: Hello, try to uncheck Intellicode-related options in tools=>options=>intellicode

Comment: `with a colleague which I previously cloned` this is a good strategy when on a tight deadline

Comment: unchecking intellicode options did not work unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly, it is related to CodeLens.

Try solving it this way:

Tools->Options->Text editor->All Languages -> CodeLens check Enable CodeLens